# In tomcat, what is catalina_home and why we use it?

Tags: tomcat, catalina

Iam new to tomcat but i knew something in java, While setting up tomcat we use to set java_home for the jdk path but all i wanted to knew what is catalina_home and why we need to setup in catalina.sh?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tomcat is actually composed of a number of components, including a Tomcat JSP engine and other connectors, but the main component is [Catalina](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Catalina.html), which provides the implementation of the servlet specification.  When starting the Tomcat server, it's [Catalina](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Catalina.html) that is actually starting.  The variable 'catalina_home' is a configuration property that stores the location of the [Catalina](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Catalina.html) files.

These are the configuration files in Tomcat's "$CATALINA_BASE/conf" directory:

- catalina.policy
- catalina.properties
- logging.properties
- content.xml
- server.xml
- tomcat-users.xml
- web.xml

Answer (score 14):

`CATALINA_HOME` is the folder where Apache Tomcat is installed e.g. `c:\program files\Apache Tomcat` or `/usr/apache/tomcat`. It is the folder where you unzip Tomcat in the first place (when you install from zip).

`CATALINA_HOME` is necessary because a lot of the files Tomcat will use are referred to from the variable `CATALINA_HOME`. For instance log files are written inside `CATALINA_HOME/logs`. Configuration is read from `CATALINA_HOME/conf`.

If you try to run Tomcat with the wrong `CATALINA_HOME`, things will go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

### Setting CATALINA_HOME is not required

The file `catalina.bat|sh` is dependent on CATALINA_HOME. Catalina home is the base directory used to

- set environment variables (setenv.bat)
- set classpath (setclasspath.bat)

among other things.

Simply run the `startup.sh|bat` or `catalina.sh|bat` from the tomcat directory. It will automatically set the variable.

```
rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
cd ..
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"
:gotHome
```

#### CATALINA_BASE == CATALINA_HOME

Both the variables do the same thing, they are used as base directory variables. If CATALINA_BASE is not set, CATALINA_HOME is copied into it.

```bash
# Copy CATALINA_BASE from CATALINA_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CATALINA_BASE" ] && CATALINA_BASE="$CATALINA_HOME"
```